# A portable check for infinity and not-a-number

Tags: c, c++98

I am looking for something that does not use assumptions regarding the implementation of the floating-point type, and does not use C++11/C99 methods.

Is the following code a reliable method of checking for INF and NAN? If not, what exactly can go wrong?

```
bool isfinite(double n)
{
    if(std::numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity)
    {
        double inf = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        if(std::memcmp(&n, &inf, sizeof(double)) == 0)
            return false;

        double neginf = -inf;
        if(std::memcmp(&n, &neginf, sizeof(double)) == 0)
            return false;
    }

    if(std::numeric_limits<double>::has_quiet_NaN)
    {
        double nan = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
        if(std::memcmp(&n, &nan, sizeof(double)) == 0)
            return false;

        double negnan = -nan;
        if(std::memcmp(&n, &negnan, sizeof(double)) == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Edit: Specifically, I am looking for a way to accomplish this within the language, and not relying on compiler intrinsic functions, a priori definitions, or other libraries such as *boost*.

Comment: If a floating point type has more than 1 bit combination that represents +INF, this fails.  (rare) If a floating point type has more than 1 bit combination that represents a NAN, this fails. (common)

Comment: If you use an Intel processor and long double, this is actually very likely to fail, because typically long double uses 16 bytes but only 10 are used - the remaining six bytes can be whatever they like. NaNs actually have 51 bits that can be used to identify what kind of NaN we have.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I have code that will need to run on weird machines, where you cannot trust anything in terms of libraries/implementation.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::isnan` and `std::isinf`

Comment: @ChrisDodd Both [std::isnan](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) and [std::isinf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf) are C++11.

Comment: there is a nan trick if (someFloat != someFloat){/*only true for nan*/}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confident OP's code does not always work.

A `double` (e.g. [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary64)) has a non-unique NaN binary representation of:
(`s` is the sign bit.)

```
s1111111 1111baaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
```

Where not all `baa ... aaa` is 0.  (if `baa ... aaa` is all 0, then it is `INF`.)  The difference between quiet NaN and signaling NaN is often signified with the value of `b`.

The salient issue is that not all NaN have the same bit pattern.  The testing proposed for `double` against a single bit pattern is an insufficient test for NaN detection.

Suggest instead a portable test that does not rely on NaN, nor Infinity existing in a given C's platform.

```
double x;

// NAN are never arithmetically equal, even to themselves.
if (x != x) NaN_Detected();
if (x > DBL_MAX || x < -DBL_MAX) Inf_Detected();
```

[Edit] compare fix: thanks to @Jongware

Comment: `x != x` -- sheer poetry ... if it works. Would this need a `volatile`, to prevent an opportunistic compiler from bluntly replacing it with a `false`?

Comment: @Jongware No I do not think `volatile` is needed.  Good compilers know they cannot optimize FP this way: All NaN logically fail arithmetic compares like `x != x, x == x, x >= x, x > x` but `memcmp(x,x,sizeof(x)` is 0.  BTW: There is a reverse situation with typical FP too.  Consider `+0.0 == -0.0` is true, both arithmetically equal but `memcmp()` is not 0.

Comment: Thanks! But note: DBL_MAX is the largest possible value away from 0 -- positive or negative. DBL_MIN is the closest value to 0, also positive or negative. So this needs `fabs(x)` twice. (<strike>On an additional note, filling a double with pseudo-random values I never seem to get either :)</strike> (I just got a Nan after several thousands' iterations.)

Comment: @Jongware fixed. (Up too late with my Uncle Sam date).  Try `x = strtod("INF",0,0);` or `x = INFINITY;`

Comment: Okay, thanks again -- that did the trick. Both checks work now.

Comment: Is `x != x` not relying on an implementation that follows the IEEE standard though?

Comment: Follow-up on my 'volatile' question: disassembly for that line is `ucomisd %xmm0, %xmm0`. So apparently it's left to the FPU to Do The Right Thing.

Comment: @Nicolas `x != x` is relying on _some_ standard, be it IEEE or otherwise.  C spec does help much as it does not specify much detail about the plethora of FP issues.  So it is _possible_ for FP to have Not-a-numbers and not be IEEE compliant (and thus x != x is always false).  I have worked with FP that does not have NaN/Inf/sub-normals.  But all systems I've encountered that have NaN have strived for IEEE compliance.  So if it did not work, it is a compiler bug.

Comment: @OP.  A bit more: Pre C99 has lacks portable functions like the _informative_ `isinf()`, int `isnan()`.  So there is no pre C99 way to have a portable solution without some assumptions, such as adherence to IEEE or complete lack of INF/NaN.  The above works with IEEE and IEEE like FP packages for NaN and `x > DBL_MAX` speaks for itself as a candidate for infinity detection.  Devil's advocate in me also says `DBL_MAX` may be non-compliant and be set to infinity.  If I was writing _portable_ code, I would conditionally use `isnan() isinf()` as able, falling to this answer else wise.

Comment: @chux This is what I am doing at the moment as well, with a check for C99. If not present, I compare to defined values for +/- INF and use `x == x` for NAN. Both of which uses IEEE 754, but I guess it's rare that an implementation does not. I'm not writing for microcontrollers. I was wondering if the standard has an intrinsic way to do it.

Comment: @OP: IMO, IEEE 754 does not outline _how_ to determine things like NaN-ness, but does spells what is NaN.  (Note: I do not think IEEE 754 spells out bit patterns for quiet vs signaling NaNs, but certainly some conventions are emerging - I could be behind on that.)  The history of NaN coding is wrought with inconsistencies/unawareness.  Consider FP code: `if (x > y) do_gt(); else if (x < y) do_lt(); else do_eq();`  when it should end with `else if (x == y) do_eq(); else do_uncomparable()`.